# Nested Dict To DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

CAN ANYONE HELP

```py
msg = {'e': 'kline',        
       'E': 1672157513375, 
       's': 'BTCUSDT', 
       'k': {
             't': 1672157460000, #REQUIRE, CONVERT MS TO DATETIME,
                                 #RENAME AS TIME, AS INDEX
             'T': 1672157519999, 
             's': 'BTCUSDT', 
             'i': '1m', 
             'f': 2388965371, 
             'L': 2388969270, 
             'o': '16787.32000000', #REQUIRE RENAME AS OPEN
             'c': '16783.23000000', #REQUIRE RENAME AS CLOSE
             'h': '16789.41000000', #REQUIRE RENAME AS HIGH
             'l': '16782.69000000', #REQUIRE RENAME AS LOW
             'v': '149.27507000',   #REQUIRE RENAME AS VOLUME
             'n': 3900, 
             'x': False, 
             'q': '2505669.98288240', 
             'V': '59.70465000', 
             'Q': '1002207.92308370', 
             'B': '0'
            }
}
```

Time = k(t),datetime

Open = k(o),dtype float

High = k(h),dtype float

Low = k(l), dtype float

Close = k(c), dtype float

Volume = k (v),dtype float

index give as,
k(t) convert this millisecond to datetime,
and converted give as index
language python

WHAT I TRYING:

```
def getdata(msg):
    frame = pd.DataFrame(msg)
    #DONT UNDERSTOOD
    frame = frame.loc[frame['k']['t'],frame['k']['t'],frame['k']['t'],
                      frame['k']['t'],frame['k']['t'],frame['k']['t']]
    #SOME UNDERSTOOD
    frame.columns = ["Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"]
    frame.set_index("Time",inplace=True)
    frame.index = pd.to_datetime(frame.index,unit='ms')
    frame = frame.astype(float)
    return frame

getdata(msg)
```

REQUIRE OUTPUT:

```
Time                 Open     High     Low      Close   Volume


2022-12-27 16:11:00  16787.7  16789.4  16782.6  16783.2 149
```

<3

Comment: pls dont minus vote this is real problem using binance socket manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using json_normalize():

```
df = (pd
      .json_normalize(data=msg["k"])[["t", "o", "h", "l", "c", "v"]]
      .rename(columns={"t": "Time", "o": "Open", "h": "High", "l": "Low", "c": "Close", "v": "Volume"})
      )

df["Time"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], unit="ms")
    .dt.tz_localize("UTC")
    .dt.tz_localize(None)
    .dt.floor("S")
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Time            Open            High             Low           Close        Volume
0 2022-12-27 16:11:00  16787.32000000  16789.41000000  16782.69000000  16783.23000000  149.27507000
```

Comment: TYSM <3, Thakyousomuch

Comment: If you feel I answered your question please mark it as solved and upvote if you want.